# ¿Como hacer zoom en un polígono de google maps?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estimada comunidad, estoy intentando hacer que el mapa que se dibuja en el navegador basado en un arreglo de coordenadas enviadas al poligono de Google Maps haga un zoom diferente a 1, he intantado cambiarlo directamente en (zoom: 5) y no funciona, asi que les comparto el codigo de lo que he podido realizar hasta el momento:

https://jsfiddle.net/bcastro94/8f39vdgj/3/

Quiero aclarar que comparto un enlace de JSFIDDLE porque el javascript de este codigo en particular es demasiado grande por el arreglo de coordenadas.

Agradeceria por completo de que me puedan ayudar a solventar este inconveniente, saludos.

Comment: Has probado con el metodo setZoom de la API de Google Maps para JS?

Comment: La verdad no, como es la sintaxis en ese caso @hrkns

Comment: He usado solo lo básico de la API de Google Maps, pero supuse que capaz después de hacer todas esas operaciones podias hacer que actualices el zoom manualmente usando el metodo setZoom https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/map-setzoom

Comment: Puedes hacer un ejemplo mínimo con un poligono mas chico https://jsfiddle.net/80v9udhL/